# Incorrect packet format, calling SAP service from C# with WSDL file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, service, saprfc

I am attempting to call a SAP service using a WSDL file provided to me. I am getting this error:

> Unexpected Packet Format

I have tested the service using SOAPUI and everything is working from there. When I call the service from my C# application I get the error referenced above.

**Relative Information**

- Service is provided from SAP
- Service was imported using a .WSDL file
- Testing inside Console Application
- I have tested other services provided by my SAP group that worked just fine.

**Code**

```
ZPC_DROP_DOWN_VALUESClient client = new ZPC_DROP_DOWN_VALUESClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "ERICO";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";
ZpcDropDownValues vals = new ZpcDropDownValues();
vals.Uom = "X";
ZpcDropDownValuesResponse Response = new ZpcDropDownValuesResponse();            

try
{
    Response = client.ZpcDropDownValues(vals);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

**Here is the stack trace:**

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at https://r3snd.yaskawa.com:8000/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zpc_drop_down_values/410/zpc_drop_down_values/zpc_drop_down_values that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'r3snd.yaskawa.com'
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace:
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
> at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
> at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
> at ServicesFromSAP.TableReference.ZPC_DROP_DOWN_VALUES.ZpcDropDownValues(ZpcDropDownValuesRequest request)
> at ServicesFromSAP.TableReference.ZPC_DROP_DOWN_VALUESClient.ServicesFromSAP.TableReference.ZPC_DROP_DOWN_VALUES.ZpcDropDownValues(ZpcDropDownValuesRequest request) in C:\Users\eric_obermuller\source\repos\ServicesFromSAP\ServicesFromSAP\Connected Services\TableReference\Reference.cs:line 339
> at ServicesFromSAP.TableReference.ZPC_DROP_DOWN_VALUESClient.ZpcDropDownValues(ZpcDropDownValues ZpcDropDownValues1) in C:\Users\eric_obermuller\source\repos\ServicesFromSAP\ServicesFromSAP\Connected Services\TableReference\Reference.cs:line 345
> at ServicesFromSAP.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\eric_obermuller\source\repos\ServicesFromSAP\ServicesFromSAP\Program.cs:line 33

I am not sure what the issue is. This service was provided to me for testing/learning purposes so I could start learning how to use their services. Is there some kind of setting I am not aware of?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Not sure if I need to set the timeout to be longer or something along those lines. I have looked everywhere for an answer and it seems this is a case by case issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I figured out the issue. Originally when testing this application the request was actually sent to me as an Http request.

**Endpoint in App.Config**

```
<endpoint address="http://R3SND.yaskawa.com:8000/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zpc_drop_down_values/410/zpc_drop_down_values/zpc_drop_down_values"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ZPC_DROP_DOWN_VALUES"
            contract="TableReference.ZPC_DROP_DOWN_VALUES" name="ZPC_DROP_DOWN_VALUES" />
```

When I tried the application I got an error that said "Invalid URI Http, Https expected". Not quite knowing what was going on I changed my endpoint address to Https instead of Http. That is where the referenced error above happened.

While messing around I changed it back to Http and realized the error was being thrown because I was using HttpsTransport instead of HttpTransport.

**Https Transport**

```
<httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Basic" />
```

**Http Transport(correct one)**

```
<httpTransport authenticationScheme="Basic" />
```

I hope this can help someone else down the line because it was driving me insane!

Thank you all for looking at my question.

Comment: Can you please provide full code snippet. I am also stuck with the same error of missing Endpoint. I am not sure what endpoint I should give?

My Code is also working in SOAP UI. It will be very helpful for me

Comment: If you import your wsdl file into the project. You should see the above code in your app.config. check the http transport section and verify it matches the correct type for your wsdl file.

Comment: Is there any need to pass Remote address and EndPoint somewhere? Because I was getting related to specifying EndPoint